# Using if block in dbt models

Tags: jinja2, dbt

Apologies for asking dumb question. But I tried many different approaches but none of them seems to work.

I have a requirement to select data from 2 different tables based on the variable. I am trying to do that in dbt models with if statement but it doesn't seem to work.

Model looks something like thins:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
{% if enable_whitelisting == 'true' %}
    {{ ref('accounts_whitelisted') }}    accounts
{% else %}
        {{ ref('accounts') }}   accounts
{% endif %}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Ravi. Would you be able to share a bit more information? Do you get an error when it runs? Could you share what the compiled code looks like? How are you passing the variable?

Comment: Hi @dylanbaker, I fixed my issue. I answered below. The variable name had to be placed in var()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got this working eventually. Have to put the variable name within the **var()**

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
{% if var('enable_whitelisting') == 'true' %}
    {{ ref('accounts_whitelisted') }}    accounts
{% else %}
        {{ ref('accounts') }}   accounts
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: where enable_whitelisting was coming from? is it not a column from the model?

Comment: It's a variable from either the command line or from the config